# Parse Xml to get attribute value in android using android SAX packages mathods

Tags: android, xml, sax

I am parsing an XML file in which certain element having attributes.
Is there any way to get the attribute value using methods given in android SAX package?

Comment: can you please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my real answer. :) You probably meant android.sax.

Then you need to add a [StartElementListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/StartElementListener.html) and in start() you'll find your [Attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html).